# Duplicate instance of Bayeux Server created

Tags: cometd, bayeux

I'm having a problem with my CometD Application. It looks like its creating multiple instances of the Bayeux Server. My configuration Files look like the following and i'm using Web Sockets as Transport/GigaSpaces to deploy the Application (which uses its own embedded jetty Server). Just wondering if I've misconfigured something in the following setup?

WEB.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>CometDApplication</display-name>  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>     
        <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometdServlet</servlet-class>      
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jsonContext</param-name>
            <param-value>org.cometd.server.JacksonJSONContextServer</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transports</param-name>      
            <param-value>org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport</param-value>
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.openspaces.pu.container.jee.context.ProcessingUnitContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/META-INF/spring/pu.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

POM.XML:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>bayeux-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-websocket-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>                        
            <version>7.6.8.v20121106</version>
        </dependency>
```

My Applcation Context File (pu.XML):

```
<bean id="Bayeux" class="org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="options">
        <map>
            <entry key="logLevel" value="0" />
            <entry key="timeout" value="15000" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="transports">
        <list>          
            <bean id="websocketTransport" class="org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport">
                <constructor-arg ref="Bayeux" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="jsonTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONTransport">
                <constructor-arg ref="Bayeux" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="jsonpTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONPTransport">
                <constructor-arg ref="Bayeux" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>        
</bean>


<bean id="ContextExporter" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="org.cometd.bayeux">
                <ref local="Bayeux" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed creating two instances of `BayeuxServer`, one created by the `CometdServlet` you define in `web.xml` and one created by Spring.

Like stated in the [CometD and Spring integration documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_services_integration_spring), if you use Spring to initialize CometD, then your whole `BayeuxServer` configuration must be in Spring.
Don't duplicate it in `web.xml`.

Furthermore, since you define a `<load-on-startup>` element, the `CometdServlet` is initialized *before* Spring's `ContextLoaderListener`, creating a `BayeuxServer` instance before Spring gets the chance to create its own and export it.

Remove all `<init-param>` from `web.xml`, remove `<load-on-startup>` and you should be good: the servlet will be lazily initialized and will find the Spring-created `BayeuxServer` exported correctly, without creating an additional instance.

Comment: Hi Simone, Thanks for your response.  I've tried out your suggestions and it looks like i'm still getting multiple instances of the Bayeux created. I've had a look at your suggested post on Spring integration and removed the <INIT-PARM> and <Load-on-startup> parms from the WEB.XML. Is there something else i could be doing wrong in the above configuration?